# ode; zero input response: what does q(D)y = 0 mean?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

my textbook on ordinary differential equations has a chapter on system modeling, and I 'm not sure if I understand what is meant by

> The zero-input response is the solution to  $q(\mathbf{D})y=0$,
> $y(0)=a_0$, $y'(0)=a_1$, ...

One of the examples given of how to determine the zero-input respnse from a system modeled by q(**D**) is

$q(\mathbf{D}) = (\mathbf{D} + 1)^2 + 4$,  $y(0)=1$,  $y'(0)=3$

I can see how the answer

$y=e^{-t}(\cos(2t) + 2\sin(2t))$

is derived by searching for the characteristic modes from the standard basis, but then I recalculated the linear equation with the derivative back from this answer, and I expected the result to be a constant 0.

I tried this in matlab:

```
syms x 

y = exp(-x) * (cos(2*x) + 2*sin(2*x));

qD = (diff(y) + y)^2 + 4*y;

diffy = diff(y);

hold on

fplot(y, [0 5])
fplot(qD, [0 5])
fplot(diffy, [0 5])

%fplot(hn)

legend ('y', 'qD', 'diffy')
```

but I got anything but a constant 0 for $q(\mathbf D)$.

so is my matlab formula for $q(\mathbf D)$ wrong? or what else is meant by $q(\mathbf{D})=0$?

regards, Danny.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$q(\mathbf{D}) = (\mathbf{D} + 1)^2 + 4$$
$q(D)y=0$ (and not $q(D)=0)$  means:
$$( (\mathbf{D} + 1)^2 + 4)y=0$$
$$(D^2+2D+5)y=0$$
$$y''+2y'+5y=0$$
Characteristic polynomial is:
$$(r+1)^2-4i^2=0 \implies r=-1 \pm 2i$$
$$\implies y(t)=e^{-t}(c_1 \cos(2t)+c_2 \sin (2t)$$

Comment: yes, thanks!  y = diff(y,2) + 2*diff(y) + 5*y; does give me a constant 0 result!!!

Comment: How comes ? You mean on mathlab ? @velsd  And is it $y=3$ or $y'(0)=3$ ?

Comment: try to write $qD=D^2+2D+5$ note that $D^2$ is not a square but means differentiate twice. i don't know exactly the code in Mathlab @velsd

Comment: Maybe $D^2 = $diff(diff$(y))$ ??? Differentiate twice

Comment: $qD= diff(diff(y))+2diff(y)+5y$ Maybe ?

Comment: I corrected my question for the initial values, apologies. And yes, it is the matlab formula that I meant with qD = diff(y,2) + 2*diff(y) + 5*y; this now plots as a constant 0 line, which makes me confident that I correctly understood the original problem q(D)y=0, thanks a lot!!

Comment: diff(y,2) is the second derivative in matlab, indeed

Comment: You're welcome @velsd

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are using $\mathbf{D}$ as the derivative operator. So an ODE of a dynamic system can be written as:
$$q(\mathbf{D})y(t)=u(t)$$ being $q(\mathbf{D})$ a polynomial of $\mathbf{D}$ and $u(t)$ the input of the system.

The zero input response of a system is the response taking into account only its internal dynamics. So $y(t)$ is the solution of the equation $q(\mathbf{D})y(t)=0$.

The function you calculated in matlab is already the application of the operator $\mathbf{D}$, as you are using the `diff` functions, so it is expected to result 0.